# Powershell scopes

Tags: powershell, scope

In a Powershell console if I do:

```
PS C:\Users\Moomin\Documents> $global:myVar = "global"
PS C:\Users\Moomin\Documents> $myVar
global
PS C:\Users\Moomin\Documents> $myVar = "local"
PS C:\Users\Moomin\Documents> $myVar
local
PS C:\Users\Moomin\Documents> $global:myVar
local
```

Why doesn't the last statement return `global`?

Even more confusing if I then do:

```
PS C:\Users\Moomin\Documents> $myVar = $null
PS C:\Users\Moomin\Documents> $global:myVar
```

I get nothing returned. I expected to get `global` returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the scope is based on the function you are in if you are using the console not in a function you are operating on the global.

```
PS C:\> $myvar = 4
PS C:\> function PrintMyVar{$myvar = 6;$myvar}
PS C:\> PrintMyVar
6
PS C:\> $myvar
4
```

Answer (score 2):

From MS about_scope:

```
Local:  
    The current scope. The local scope can be the global 
    scope or any other scope.
```

This is why `$myVar` gets overwritten and nothing is returned on the last line.